# Вставка java.time.LocalDate в MySQL с использованием JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, время, jdbc

Мне нужно сохранить в БД локальную дату(не указывая часовой пояс). В моей программе на java эта дата храниться в `java.time.LocalDate`. В MySQL эта дата хранится в типе данных `DATE`.

Я использую `DATE` и `java.time.LocalDate` потому что, насколько я понял из документации, эти типы данных не сохраняют никакой информации про часовой пояс, а хранят только день, месяц и год.

Я работаю с БД через JDBC, через `mysql-connector-java` версии 8.0.15. Вставка делается через `PreparedStatement`. Упрощенный код запроса такой:

```
String INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO local_dates VALUES (?)"
```

Значение параметра я устанавливаю через setDate

```
LocalDate localDate = ...;
PreparedStatment s = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_QUERY);
s.setDate(1, Date.valueOf(localDate));
```

Но в БД вставляется не та дата, что я указываю. Например, если в переменной `localDate` лежит `'2019-04-15'` то в базу попадает `'2019-04-14'`. То есть дата уменьшается на один день.

Изначально я думал что проблема в использовании `java.sql.Date.valueOf`, ведь `java.sql.Date` внутри использует устаревший `java.util.Date`. Прочитав что спецификация JDBC начиная с версии 4.2 поддерживает работу с классами `java.time`, я попытался использовать вместо `setDate` метод`setObject`:

```
s.setObject(1, localDate);
```

Но результат остался прежним.

Почему при вставке изменяется дата, и как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Странно, у меня есть проект где все точно так же как у вас и все правильно сохраняется. А как и где вы смотрите результат сохранения?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець смотрю через DataGrip(IDE для баз данных). Да и в самой программе, при считывании из БД дата тоже неправильная.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець причем при отладке я обнаружил что дата изменяется именно после вызова `s.setObject`. В `setObject` передается нормальная дата, а после вызова `setObject`,  в `PreparedStatement` попадает уже неправильная

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решил проблему следующим способом:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = dateTimeFormatter.format(date);
s.setString(parameterIndex, formattedDate);
```